# Clipping MrSID raster image, without decompressing clipped raster, in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, raster, clip, mrsid

I am using ArcView ArcMap10 and when I clip a raster using tools/data management tools/raster/clip. The Clipped file ends up much larger than the original file.  Specifically I am trying to clip a MrSID file that is 2.6gb, the clipped file ends up being 54.gb.  I have tried playing with the environment setting and compression rates trying to convert to a JP2 with no luck.

I am fairly new to GIS.